# How to address a Dr. des.?

Tags: etiquette, germany, titles

How do you address a **Dr. des.** (Doctor designatus), for example in e-mails?

- Dr. John Doe
- Dr. des. John Doe
- John Doe
- …?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When can you call yourself doctor?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9925/when-can-you-call-yourself-doctor)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the formal title is **Dr. des.**, there are good reasons to simply use the form of address you would use to a “final” doctor: the title is only temporary, and the person will eventually have the title or *Dr.*; moreover, PhD candidates having freshly attained their goal will probably enjoy you using it.

---

For those who wonder what *Dr. des.* is, it's a [temporary title](http://www.unilu.ch/eng/promotionspruefung_824753.html), like US presidents are “president elect”:

> Following a successful defence, the title of *Doctor designatus* (*Dr. des.*) may be used until the doctoral degree is gained.