# How should I state my masters degree in my CV if I finished the program, but the ceremony won't be held for several months?

Tags: cv, degree, graduation

I'm currently updating my CV because recently I finished a master program. although the ceremony is going to be on March, I don't have the diploma yet. How should I state this in my CV?

Comment: Related: [What date should I use for graduation?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14503/what-date-should-i-use-for-graduation). Has your degree been conferred yet?

Comment: Yes, the university just confirmed me that I fulfilled all requirements and I'm listed for the ceremony

Comment: Wonderful, thanks, I think that is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out from the university when the degree is *conferred*. This may be before or after the ceremony (it could be already conferred). (Also see: [What date should I use for graduation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14503/what-date-should-i-use-for-graduation))

- If the degree has already been conferred, you can write that you have a masters degree (the ceremony is irrelevant).
- If it hasn't, write that you have completed the degree requirements, and expect the degree to be conferred on X date.