# What is the actual date of PhD award (in India)

Tags: phd, thesis, postdocs, degree, defense

I have been awarded my PhD long back and I have my official award certificate from the university given in the annual degree convocation. However, often a question comes to my mind - What is my actual date of award of PhD?

Is it the **date I submitted the final version of thesis** or **the date I defended my thesis** or **the date of degree convocation on which I received my degree** (the date of convocation is mentioned in the certificate, too)?

In all State-run organizations in India, it is often required to fill in the details about the date of PhD. However, I am not able to find an clear explanation anywhere.

PS: In India, unlike UK where you are often conferred with an award before the graduation ceremony, the degree is awarded only at the ceremony. However, the candidate can apply for a provisional degree certificate if the data of the ceremony is very far.
Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit informative, however, I am looking the answer which would come from someone who has had an experience in India in this matter especially in State run organizations.

Comment: It is awarded in the ceremony. That is what the ceremony is for!

Comment: "_I am looking the answer which would come from someone who has had an experience in India in this matter especially in State run organizations_" Please **ask this question to the State run organization**. We are not them, we don't have the **official** answer.

Comment: Thanks @Nobody, and you right when you say, "We are not them,...". However, I have faith that some of the "We"s are out there who have had such experience(s).

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩, I feel the same, too.

Comment: If a State-run organization requires you to fill in the details about the date of PhD, it is their job to answer your question. Personal experience may not count.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question to me: It is on-topic, specific, and probably answerable by any experienced academic in the Indian system.

Comment: Meanwhile, I got this page: https://www.grad.ubc.ca/faq/11095. It makes a clarification, though not from India.

Comment: Please read [this comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14503/what-date-should-i-use-for-graduation#comment26993_14509). This is why you **must** ask this question to the State-run organization. I am talking about UGC or other government agencies.

Comment: @Nobody, this is the same link as provided by Brian up there.

Comment: Please do not count on somebody else's experience. If somebody says one way, a State run organization says another way, you'll fail to get a job offer because of incorrect PhD degree award date.