# Ph.D. candidate vs Ph.D

Tags: phd, cv

I have already submitted my Ph.D. thesis to my committee and plan to defend my thesis. I want to prepare an updated CV.

In my situation, what should I write in the CV:

> **Ph.D. candidate**

or just

> **Ph.D**

Comment: If I remember correctly, Ph.D. Candidate is used after passing the oral comprehensive exam and while waiting for the college or university to complete paperwork on finalizing your Ph.D. work.

Comment: @drsnark I think that is not accurate. *Ph.D. candidate* is the status after concluding all course work (if there is any) and passing a qualification exam, where you deliver and defend your project of thesis.

Comment: @The Doctor I think you are right.  I was not remembering the correct order.

Comment: Related https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10972/phd-candidate-vs-phd-student and https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9925/when-can-you-call-yourself-doctor

Comment: What is the updated CV for?

Comment: @StrongBad For applying for postdoc position

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Typically, one writes **Ph.D., 2018 (expected)**.

If you have a short description (e.g., bullet points) after this heading, you can also put the expected graduation/defense month or something to the effect of "thesis submitted 25 May 2018" in this area.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't defended yet, I would list (expected).

If you have defended and committee passed and thesis turned in and ruler lady passed and all done, done but are just waiting for the 6 month wheels to churn and send you a sheepskin, I would keep it simple and just list the Ph.D. as done.  If you stop using months on your CV and move to years, this helps you.