# Can I officially use the Ph.D. as the highest educational attainment while waiting for graduation?

Tags: application, credentials

I finished all the requirements for a Ph.D. degree at a university in Hong Kong. This month, I received a letter from our Graduate School confirming that the University Senate has approved my graduation and has “awarded” me the “degree of Doctor of Philosophy.” The e-Transcript also says the same, and it notes that I will receive my diploma in November 2022 after the Commencement Exercise.

When applying for jobs, is it okay now to declare my highest educational status as a Ph.D. holder, or do I need to wait for the release of the diploma?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9925/when-can-you-call-yourself-doctor Closely related, maybe duplicate

Comment: I never went to my graduation ceremony, yet still am a PhD.

Comment: Yes, for all practical purposes.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for the links and comments. I've encountered the thread a while ago. I posted the question since the older thread did not dwell much on using the Ph.D. in the context of job application. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Customs differ between countries. As you received a note of being awarded the Ph.D. as of August 2022, you can and should use it now as your highest degree in a job application. In the cover letter, you should mention that you will receive your diploma in November 2022 after the graduation exercise, as an employer might want to see it. However, if someone asks your university about the degree, the university should confirm that it has been already awarded to you, as the e-transcripts show.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice!