# Can I call myself Dr. after getting provisional PhD certificate in India?

Tags: cv, india

I have just passed my PhD final viva voce and got the provisional certificate for PhD in India. The provisional certificate states that "The candidate has passed the PhD viva voce examination and fulfills the requirement(s) for the award of Doctor of Philosophy" . However, the actual degree certificate will be provided during the convocation ceremony as per norms.

So, can I write myself as Dr. from now on in my resume, postdoctoral and job applications- or I have to wait until I get the actual degree? Is there any legal or official regulations for when a person can call himself Dr. Something?

Comment: This depends heavily on your location. Are you asking specifically for communication inside India?

Comment: Related / potential duplicate: [When can you call yourself doctor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9925/when-can-you-call-yourself-doctor)

Comment: I am asking for communication inside India and also about  intrnational convention (if there is any)